# Dracoloader not loaded through ascene

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js

Hi I want to use a GLTF with draco. I get the object but when adding it to the scene it says:

```
components:gltf-model:warn THREE.GLTFLoader: No DRACOLoader instance provided.
```

I have my dracoDecoderPath set inside my a-scene:

```
<a-scene
      sceneviewer
      gltf-model="dracoDecoderPath: https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/;"
      vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
      embedded
      arjs='sourceType: webcam; sourceWidth:1280; sourceHeight:960; displayWidth: 1280; displayHeight: 960; debugUIEnabled: false;'>
```

Comment: Can you share code with https://glitch.com/~aframe? otherwise it will be hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  AFRAME.registerComponent('sceneviewer', {
        init: function () {
          const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
          dracoLoader.setDecoderConfig({ type: 'js' });
          dracoLoader.setDecoderPath("https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/1.4.0/");
          this.el.sceneEl.systems["gltf-model"].data.dracoDecoderPath = 'https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/1.4.0/';
          this.el.sceneEl.systems["gltf-model"].dracoLoader = dracoLoader;
        },
```